# AngularJS - Can we remove/delete module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angular-module

I'm trying to clear memory of previous module of my app which Im not going to use after I've routed to a different location.

So for example my "WebApp" is my main angular module of my app which has dependency of "catalogApp", "PaymentApp", etc modules. I want to remove the previous module as and when I route from 1 module to another.

So, Can we remove/delete module?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about deleting modules as such. But you can use [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) to lazy load modules only when they are required.

Comment: I am also aware of ocLazyLoad. But I want to clear JS memory as and when I route from one sub app to another.